# How do I install an external maven plugin into my Codenvy maven project?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, external, codenvy

I'd like to add the plugin [here](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda/tree/master/retrolambda-maven-plugin) to my existing Maven project in Codenvy. The aim is to be able to use lambda notation in Java 7, as Codenvy doesn't yet have support for Java 8. I've looked around and I don't know if it is just my incompetence, but I can't seem to find a way of doing it. Unless I'm missing something or just don't understand it fully, it seems it isn't possible.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Java 8 in Codenvy (however there's no code assistant support)

You may use a custom runner with codenvy/jdk8_maven3_tomcat8 image (inherit from it).

Lambda expressions will work, although you will see errors in the editor.

As to your plugin, do you want to reference a local plugin in your project's pom.xml